# (VB.net) Having a picturebox as a property of a class

Tags: arrays, vb.net, class, picturebox

I am currently making a space invaders game in vb (for a school project otherwise I would steer clear of this for making a game...)

I have a class called Invader, where the information on each enemy will be stored. Part of this is having a picturebox to display the image of the invader, which I have added as a property of the class.

```vb
Public Class Invader

' PROPERTIES '

Property X As Integer           'The X coordinate'
Property Y As Integer           'The Y coordinate'
Property PicBox As PictureBox    'The picturebox that holds the invader picture'
Property Type As String         'The enemy type that the invader is'
Property Health As Integer      'The health of the invader'
Property Speed As Integer       'The number of pixels that the invader moves when Move() is called'
Property Alive As Boolean       'Whether the invader is alive or not'
Property Direction As Integer   'The direction that the invader is 'facing'. 1 will be right and 0 will be left'
```

The array is then declared as

```vb
    Public Enemy(0 To 3, 0 To 10) As Invader
```

The instances of the class are created from CreateEnemies()

```vb
Public Sub CreateEnemies()
    For r = 0 To 3
        For c = 0 To 10
            Enemy(r, c) = New Invader
        Next
    Next
End Sub
```

Now, I have a sub called PositionEnemies() which will position each picturebox on the game form (called frmGame) and then load the picture into it and display it.

```vb
Public Sub PositionEnemies()
    For r = 0 To 3
        For c = 0 To 10
            Enemy(r, c).PicBox = New PictureBox
            Enemy(r, c).X = 0 + ((c + 1) * 110)
            Enemy(r, c).Y = 362 - (((r + 1) * 100) - 100)
            Enemy(r, c).Alive = True
            Enemy(r, c).UpdateLocation(r, c)
            Enemy(r, c).PicBox.ImageLocation = normalinvader
            Enemy(r, c).PicBox.Load()
            Enemy(r, c).PicBox.Height = 50
            Enemy(r, c).PicBox.Width = 50
            Enemy(r, c).PicBox.Visible = True
            MsgBox(Enemy(r, c).PicBox.Created.ToString())
        Next
    Next
End Sub
```

I have added the messagebox at the end to tell me if the picturebox has been created, which at the moment always comes back as "false".

All of this is then called when frmGame loads

```vb
Private Sub frmGame_Load(ByVal sender As System.Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles MyBase.Load
    Me.Show()
    CreateEnemies()
    PositionEnemies()
End Sub
```

If you have managed to follow all that, the problem I have is that the load of frmGame completes successfully, but none of the pictureboxes are actually created for some reason (the messagebox returns "false"). I have looked at this code for so long and not been able to figure out why - I hope one of you lovely people could help me out here.

Thanks

Comment: Wow that was quick! I guess it was that simple, as it works now... as always the solution seems so obvious when you know what it is. Thanks, I appreciate the help :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Every form wants that you add the controls to be displayed to its [Controls](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.control.controls(v=vs.110).aspx) collection.
If you don't do it, no display....

```
Private Sub frmGame_Load(ByVal sender As System.Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles MyBase.Load
    CreateEnemies()
    PositionEnemies(Me)
    Me.Show()
End Sub

Public Sub PositionEnemies(ByVal f as Form)
    For r = 0 To 3
        For c = 0 To 10
            Enemy(r, c).PicBox = New PictureBox
            Enemy(r, c).X = 0 + ((c + 1) * 110)
            Enemy(r, c).Y = 362 - (((r + 1) * 100) - 100)
            Enemy(r, c).Alive = True
            Enemy(r, c).UpdateLocation(r, c)
            Enemy(r, c).PicBox.ImageLocation = normalinvader
            Enemy(r, c).PicBox.Load()
            Enemy(r, c).PicBox.Height = 50
            Enemy(r, c).PicBox.Width = 50
            Enemy(r, c).PicBox.Visible = True
            'MsgBox(Enemy(r, c).PicBox.Created.ToString())
            f.Controls.Add(Enemy(r, c).PicBox)
        Next
    Next
End Sub
```

Also, I would move the call to Show after you have created your Enemies and positioned the PictureBoxes. Of course, if the PositionEnemies is inside the frmGame class then you could use directly the Me reference without passing it.

Answer (score 0):

I think you should add

```
Me.Controls.Add(Enemy(r, c).PicBox)
```

in

```
Public Sub PositionEnemies()
```

below

```
Enemy(r, c).PicBox.Visible = True
```